# Can i transform string in template expression or lambda expression in kotlin?

Tags: lambda, kotlin

Can i transform string in template expression or lambda expression in kotlin?

```
val tm = "x = $"+"x"
val fn: (x: String) -> String = { it -> tm}
val str = fn("This is X!!!")
```

Need to get

> x = This is X!!!

**Why?:** You can receive templates, for example, from the database
PS: or your suggestions

Comment: No: the Kotlin string templates are transformed at compile-time into simple concatenation. You need different tools for string templates at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kotlin templates are evaluated at compile time - so this won't work.

You should use a 3rd party template engine.

[Freemarker](http://freemarker.org/) is such an engine with a format very similar to Kotlin's own templating format:

```
val tm = "x = \${x}"

fun fn (x: String) : String {
    val t = Template("name", StringReader(tm), Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_26))
    val out = StringWriter()
    t.process(mapOf("x" to x) ,out)
    return out.toString()
}

println (fn("This is X!!!")) // x = This is X!!!
```

Two notes:

- You won't be able to use `"$x"` on freeMarker, only `"${x}"`
- `$` sign can be escaped in a Kotlin string using `\$`

Comment: When will we use it instead of `String.format()`? They look similar.

Comment: `String.format()` is an alias for `java.lang.String.format(format, *args)` - it is useful, but it is different. [here](https://dzone.com/articles/java-string-format-examples).